# How to keep text from being the same width as its parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have created a div with information(about-info) inside of the main parent div(about). I have done this successfully but I have one problem, I put a background on the div containing about-info and the background is the same width as the width of the parent div. How do I change the width so that the width is a little bit smaller than the original parent div. I want to do this but without setting an fixed width. I already tried padding-left and padding-right but that doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>J.K Rowling</title>
  <style>
    #about {
      text-align: center;
      background: rgba(130, 74, 129, 0.70);
    }
    
    #about-info {
      display: inline-block;
      background: rgb(225, 140, 192);
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-right: 15px;
      color: white;
      width: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="about">
    <h3 id="about-info">sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info</h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can specify a `max-width` for the text and add `margin:0 auto` to center it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) affects the *content* of the element you apply it to, whereas you're looking for [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin), which affects the positioning of the element itself.

You need to add `margin-left: 15px` and `margin-right: 15px` in addition to your existing `padding` declarations. `margin` controls the offset of `#about-info` (and its background) from `#about`, whereas `padding` controls the text offset from `#about-info` itself.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
#about {
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(130, 74, 129, 0.70);
}

#about-info {
  display: inline-block;
  background: rgb(225, 140, 192);
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="about">
    <h3 id="about-info">sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info sample info</h3>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note that you can also specify a `width` for your text if you desire, though it is an `inline-block` block element, meaning that the element will constrain to the width of the text by default.

Comment: You could also set padding on the parent #about container.